# Error Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I try to work with Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer.
I created service account and download json file.
I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with full path for json file.
I create GoogleClient and Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer

```
$client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(array(
                Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY
            )
        );
$this->service = new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer($client);
```

I get list of source

```
    $this->service->projects_dataSources->
           listProjectsDataSources('projects/' . self::PROJECT_ID);
```

it works correctly.

I get list of transfers

```
$this->service->projects_locations_transferConfigs->
      listProjectsLocationsTransferConfigs(
            'projects/' . self::PROJECT_ID . '/locations/eu'
        );
```

it also works correctly.

I get credentials

```
$this->service->projects_locations_dataSources->
    checkValidCreds(            
     'projects/'.self::PROJECT_ID.'/locations/europe/dataSources/adwords',
     new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer_CheckValidCredsRequest()
        );
```

or

```
$this->service->projects_dataSources->checkValidCreds(
            'projects/'.self::PROJECT_ID.'/dataSources/adwords',
            new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer_CheckValidCredsRequest()
        );
```

both requests return null

```
object(Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer_CheckValidCredsResponse)[174]
  public 'hasValidCreds' => null
........
```

and last i try to create transfer

```
        $params = new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer_TransferConfig();
        $params->setDestinationDatasetId('stat');
        $params->setDisplayName('ID' . $adword_id);
        $params->setDataSourceId(self::DATA_SOURCE_ID);
        $params->setDataRefreshWindowDays(10);
        $params->setDisabled(false);
        $params->setParams( ['customer_id'=> (string)$adword_id]);
        return $this->service->projects_locations_transferConfigs->create(
            $this->getParent(). '/locations/europe',
            $params
        );
```

and have error

```
Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I had this error from page

```
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs/create
```

when hadn't access to bigquery.
Now i use service account and can list dataSource and transfers, but can't create datatransfer.

Can you say, what i do is wrong?

work code

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$this->client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$this->client->setAccessType("offline");
$this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$this->client->setScopes(array(
        Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY,
        ADWORDS_SCOPE
    )
);
$this->client->setRedirectUri(self::REDIRECT_URI);
$url = $this->getAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

after i authorize in google and give access.
I redirect to code

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$this->client->setAuthConfig( MCC_DIR . 'protected/config/client_secret.json');
$this->client->setAccessType("offline");
$this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$this->client->setScopes(array(
        Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY,
        ADWORDS_SCOPE
    )
);
$this->client->setRedirectUri(self::REDIRECT_URI);
$code = $_GET['code'];
$this->client->authenticate($code);
$tokken = $this->client->getAccessToken();
$this->client->setAccessToken($tokken);
$this->service = new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer($this->client);
$this->service->projects_locations_dataSources->checkValidCreds(
    'projects/1069829667403/locations/europe/dataSources/adwords',
    new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer_CheckValidCredsRequest()
);
```

and all works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default application credentials are insufficient for using BugQuery TransferConfig service (note that unless `$response->hasValidCreds` is `true`, the creds are invalid).

Please consider [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app).

Answer (score 0):

Right code.

1. You need create OAuth client ID with other type.
2. Download json credentials.
3. Get refresh token.

```php
const BQ_API_SCOPE = Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY.' '.Google_Service_Bigquery::CLOUD_PLATFORM;
const REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob';
//....

$scopes = self::BQ_API_SCOPE;
$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'authorizationUri' => self::AUTHORIZATION_URI,
    'redirectUri' => self::REDIRECT_URI,
    'tokenCredentialUri' => CredentialsLoader::TOKEN_CREDENTIAL_URI,
    'clientId' => $clientId,
    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    'scope' => $scopes
]);

echo $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri();

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
print'After approving the application, enter the authorization code here: ';
$code = trim(fgets($stdin));
fclose($stdin);
print "\n";
$oauth2->setCode($code);
$authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();
printf("Your refresh token is: %s\n\n", $authToken['refresh_token']);
```

4. Create service with google client use REFRESH_TOKKEN from 3

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setScopes(array(
        Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY,
        Google_Service_Bigquery::CLOUD_PLATFORM,
        Google_Service_Bigquery::CLOUD_PLATFORM_READ_ONLY
    )
);
if (file_exists(self::ACCESS_TOKKEN_FILE)){
    $tokken = file_get_contents(self::ACCESS_TOKKEN_FILE);
    $client->setAccessToken($tokken);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $tokken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKKEN);
        file_put_contents(self::ACCESS_TOKKEN_FILE, json_encode($tokken));
    }
}else{
    $tokken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKKEN);
    file_put_contents(self::ACCESS_TOKKEN_FILE, json_encode($tokken));
}
$this->service = new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer($client);
```